# Is there python code in the Python standard library that uses variable names that shadow builtins?

Tags: python

[**Excluding any test code that just mocks a builtin**]

Given that many builtins have been added over time, if there are multiple occurrences, I'd accept an answer showing a module or some code that was created *after* that builtin existed.

My rationale for asking is that after posting a [question](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-August/1278554.html) on the python mailing list, some of the responses indicated that there are members of the Python community that think its 
perfectly reasonable to use variable names that shadow builtins when any other name would work just as well.

I'd like to use the standard library as a gauge to how common this practice is among the various Python developers.

Comment: [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) detects this sort of thing (W0622); your best bet might be to run it (with all the other rules turned off) against Python's standard library.

Comment: There's no problem on naming variables as `str`, `list` etc inside functions. Just remember what you did.

Comment: @JBernardo.  The problem is that it makes it harder to read, harder for others to maintain, and could lead to hard-to-track-down errors.

Comment: I'm surprised you got answers -- isn't that the kind of thing that is supposed to go on [python-ideas](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-ideas)?

Comment: @Gerrat Not always. `file` is the best name for a file (because it's deprecated), In a function with 2 or 3 lines, `list` may be the best name for a list... `id` is quite common name because it's rarely used.

Comment: Also, why did you need to ask this question -- this isn't a discussion site, and a couple of the emails on the list told you exactly how to check the standard library for this.

Comment: @agf:  1. If someone on the general mailing list would have suggested python-ideas, I would have happily posted it there.  2. My question here was simple, unambiguous, non-argumentative, and clear.  I've never used any of the `linters`, and so someone mentioning that they could "help out" didn't inspire me much to download, install, and learn how to use one...just to see if it would actually highlight these cases.  I didn't ask for a discussion, but was hoping that an answer contained some additional "colour" that might flesh out whether this is a historical artifact, or still common practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The builtin I most often shadow is `id`, both because it's so useful as a variable name, and the builtin is so rarely called anyway.  A quick look in the 2.7 standard library turned up a number of uses:

```
aifc.py:            if id == marker[0]:
aifc.py:                id = _read_short(chunk)
aifc.py:            if id == self._markers[i][0]:
aifc.py:            if id == marker[0]:
difflib.py:            id = ' id="%s%s"' % (self._prefix[side],linenum)
difflib.py:            id = ''
nntplib.py:        id = ''
nntplib.py:                id = words[2]
nntplib.py:        resp, nr, id = self.statparse(resp)
pdb.py:            id = idstring[0].strip()
pdb.py:            id = idstring[1].strip()
pdb.py:        if id == '': return failed
platform.py:                id = values[2]
platform.py:    id = ''
platform.py:            id = l[1]
platform.py:        id = _id
```

There are plenty of uses of `str`, `list`, and `int` also:

```
Cookie.py:    str = str[1:-1]
mailcap.py:        str = os.environ['MAILCAPS']
mimetools.py:        str = self.typeheader
mimetools.py:            str = 'text/plain'
mimetools.py:            str = str[:i]
mimetools.py:        str = self.plisttext
mimetools.py:            str = str[1:]
mimetools.py:            str = str[end:]
rfc822.py:  str = m.getheader(name)
rfc822.py:  str = m.getrawheader(name)
smtplib.py:            str = ""
smtplib.py:            str = '%s%s' % (cmd, CRLF)
smtplib.py:            str = '%s %s%s' % (cmd, args, CRLF)
sre_parse.py:    pattern.str = str
xmllib.py:            str = res.group(1)
xmllib.py:                    str = chr(int(str[2:], 16))
xmllib.py:                    str = chr(int(str[1:]))
xmllib.py:                    str = self.entitydefs[str]
xmllib.py:                    str = '&' + str + ';'

uuid.py:            int = long(hex, 16)
uuid.py:            int = long(('%02x'*16) % tuple(map(ord, bytes)), 16)
uuid.py:            int = ((time_low << 96L) | (time_mid << 80L) |

SimpleHTTPServer.py:            list = os.listdir(path)
StringIO.py:list = f.readlines()# list of f.readline() results until EOF
StringIO.py:    list = f.readlines()
anydbm.py:        list = d.keys() # return a list of all existing keys (slow!)
asynchat.py:            self.list = deque()
asynchat.py:            self.list = deque(list)
bdb.py:        list = self.breaks[filename]
cgi.py:    list = None
cgi.py:    list = traceback.format_tb(tb, limit) + \
code.py:        list = traceback.format_exception_only(type, value)
code.py:            list = traceback.format_list(tblist)
dircache.py:        cached_mtime, list = cache[path]
dircache.py:        cached_mtime, list = -1, []
dircache.py:        list = os.listdir(path)
mailbox.py:        # list = map(long, filter(pat.match, os.listdir(self.dirname)))
mailbox.py:        list = os.listdir(self.dirname)
mailbox.py:        list = filter(pat.match, list)
mailbox.py:        list = map(long, list)
mhlib.py:list = mh.listfolders() # names of top-level folders
mhlib.py:list = mh.listallfolders() # names of all folders, including subfolders
mhlib.py:list = mh.listsubfolders(name) # direct subfolders of given folder
mhlib.py:list = mh.listallsubfolders(name) # all subfolders of given folder
mhlib.py:list = f.listmessages() # list of messages in folder (as numbers)
mhlib.py:list = f.parsesequence(seq)     # parse msgs syntax into list of messages
mhlib.py:            list = []
mhlib.py:        list = map(int, stuff.split())
multifile.py:        list = []
nntplib.py:            list = []
nntplib.py:        resp, list = self.longcmd('LIST', file)
nntplib.py:        resp, list = self.longcmd(line, file)
pickle.py:        list = stack[-1]
pickle.py:        list = stack[mark - 1]
pipes.py:    list = []
poplib.py:        list = []; octets = 0
pstats.py:        width, list = self.get_print_list(amount)
pstats.py:        width, list = self.get_print_list(amount)
pstats.py:        width, list = self.get_print_list(amount)
rexec.py:        list = []
rfc822.py:  list = m.getaddrlist(name)
shelve.py:        list = d.keys() # a list of all existing keys (slow!)
socket.py:        list = []
telnetlib.py:        list = list[:]
traceback.py:    list = []
traceback.py:    list = []
traceback.py:        list = ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n']
traceback.py:        list = list + format_tb(tb, limit)
traceback.py:        list = []
traceback.py:    list = list + format_exception_only(etype, value)
traceback.py:    list = []
xdrlib.py:        list = []
xdrlib.py:        list = []
```

and there are too many `file` and `dir` uses to post...

Comment: I'll add `open` that is quite appropriately shadowed at module level and class level in `webbrowser`, `gzip`, `imaplib`, etc.

Comment: @Ned.  Thanks for posting these examples.  I'm shocked there are so many.  From the sheer number of examples in the std lib, I have to assume that this type of thing isn't really frowned upon.  Time to adjust my point of view on this.

Comment: You shouldn't read too much into this. Your instinct to avoid shadowing where possible is a good one. Keep in mind that the code in the standard library has been contributed by many people over many years and the list of built-ins has expanded over the years. A number of the examples above are from old, mature modules that see little maintenance these days and there is a cost to changing them. Chances are that most of the shadowing examples cited would not make it into the stdlib today without being pinged in code review comments.

Comment: Two wrongs don't make a right. You can do better than the standard library, and should.

Answer (score 0):

- platform module has several uses of `id` as variable name;
- many other modules have use of `id` as variable name;
- pickle has use of `len` as variable name;
- uuid has use of `hex` as variable name;
- dom.xmlbuilder has use of `filter` as variable name;
- etc.

A directory search for built-in names between spaces can help.